# Let $A ⊂ \Bbb{R}$ be bounded above. Let B := {$x \in \Bbb{R}$ : there exists $a \in A$ such that $x < a$}. Show that sup(A) = sup(B).

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A ⊂ \Bbb{R}$ be bounded above. Let B := {$x \in \Bbb{R}$ : there exists $a \in A$ such that $x < a$}.

Show that sup(A) = sup(B).

**This does not say there exists a ∈ A such that, for all x ∈ B, x < a.**

I am having trouble trying to prove this. I'm confused by the direction saying that there doesn't exist an a ∈ A such that, for all x ∈ B, x < a, because by the construction of B it appears to me that the supremum of A is in fact larger than every element of B. So I am rather completely lost on how to prove this.

If someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I am not very good at real analysis and am trying to get better at understanding everything.

Comment: It is true that the supremum of $A$ is larger than every element of $A$. But this supremum may not belong to $A$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $A\neq\emptyset$. Then, since $A$ is bounded above, $\sup A$ exists. Take $b\in B$. Then there is some $a$ in $A$ such that $b<a$. But then $b<\sup A$. Since this occurs for every $b\in B$, $\sup B\leqslant\sup A$.

Now, suppose that $\sup B<\sup A$. take a number $x\in(\sup B,\sup A)$. Then, since $x<\sup A$, there is some $a\in A$ such that $x<a$. But then $x\in B$. This is impossible, since $x>\sup B$.

So, since $\sup B\leqslant\sup A$ and since we don't have $\sup B<\sup A$, $\sup B=\sup A$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that actually:$$B=\bigcup_{a\in A}(-\infty,a)$$

So that for every $a\in A$ we find that $(-\infty,a)\subseteq B$ and consequently $a=\sup(-\infty,a)\leq\sup B$.

This proves that: $$\sup A\leq\sup B$$

Conversely for every $x\in B$ we find that $x<a\leq\sup A$ for some $a\in A$, leading to:$$\sup B\leq\sup A$$